# Python and Selenium find element with non exact name

Tags: python, selenium

I want to login to a webpage with a form similar to this

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The problem is, in this example the name of the user field is 'user' and I will be logging in to multiple websites.

How could I find an search for multiple element names? or how to find an element with a 'username' or 'user' in the text of the name

Ie.  browser.find_element_by_name('user' or 'username')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use xpath (I think CSS supports it too, but am not sure), you can use a more complex logical expression in the selector.  For instance, selecting an element with a name that contains 'user', or one that has the name 'user' or 'username'.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "user")]')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="user" or @name="username"]')
```

(I admit to being rusty on XPATH though, so if those don't work exactly as written, please comment about it.)